# Facebook login, some doubts

Tags: php, database, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem. I have database table for registered users. And I have two ways to register a user, manually (using a form) or with facebook. When the user do it using facebook, it saves in that database table the email, name and some others, but what do I put in the password. Can I get also the password, is that unsafe? Should the user could login manually (using a login form) to acess the account he registered using facebook, if so with what password?
I'm new to social logins, do you recommend to have diferente tables for users registered manually and for users registered with social?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way:

- Add a field for the Facebook ID to your table (VARCHAR(255))
- If the user authorizes with Facebook Login, check if his User ID is already in your database
- If not, present a form where he can set his email and password

That way, you can let the user login with Facebook Login AND with email/password later.

Comment: Thank you!
It makes sense, i check if the user existis with the e-mail, even if the user uses facebook login. It would not allow two users with the same e-mail, even if they are logged with facebook or not. Is it a good pratic?

Comment: email? no, you need to check if the user exists with the facebook id, as i said...sometimes you may not even get an email from a facebook user. of course you could check for both if the email is visible.

Comment: Understand, and in exemple, i have a facebook account with e-mail xx@gmail.com, and i'm already registered in the website with that e-mail. What should the website do when i try to login with the facebook account. Create a new account or access to the existing account?
Sorry for asking so many questions... and for my english :D

Comment: well, i believe you could just add the facebook id to the existing mail. after all you have to approve your email on facebook afaik, so it must be owned by the facebook user.

Comment: Ok, i really appreciated your help.